# Accessing the http request in spring security custom expression

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to write a custom spring security expression with PreAuthorize.
I want to achieve this:

```
@PreAuthorize(customAuthCheck(param1, param2))
@RestController
public String getRestrictedInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // 
}
```

where param1, param2 depends on the business logic.

In my `AuthSecurityExpressionRoot` class:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
    public boolean customAuthCheck(String param1, String param2) {
        // check authorization
    }
}
```

The problem is, I want to access the http request (specifically, the "Authorization" header, and the httpMethod) inside the `customAuthCheck` method. How can I implement that?

Comment: Why would you need the `Authorization` header in a custom check? That should already be done in a filter and stored somewhere.

Comment: as @M.Deinum is saying if you want to check something in the Authorization do it inside a filter, PreAuthorize stuff give you access to security objects (Authentication, SecurityContextHolder) so when your filter has done the job you can get the results from those objects from your custom PreAuthorize and perform any check on them

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your answers. For my project, inside the jwt token, there is info about the user. I need that info, combining with the two params, to verify user authos.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the entire request to your MethodSecurityExpressionOperations object, then extract whatever headers you need.  In your case, use this:

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
    public boolean customAuthCheck(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String jwtString = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        // decode/process the JWT
        // check authorization
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
@PreAuthorize(customAuthCheck(#request))
@RestController
public String getRestrictedInfo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // 
}
```

You can pass other params along with the header too, if you want, as long as they are part of the method signature, e.g.:

```
@PreAuthorize(customAuthCheck(#param1, #request))
public String getRestrictedInfo(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam String param1) {
    //
}
```